# Android layout Fix

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want an android Top menu section like the below image [image]

But Now I am getting the layout like this

[image]

This is My Code used in main xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"
            android:background="@drawable/back_gradient" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me how can i achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Correction in `TextView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"
            android:background="@drawable/back_gradient" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"           //here
            android:layout_weight="1"            //here
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="19sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this Layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/back_gradient" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/search" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` for your `TextView`.
Try following data

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:background="#123456"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
    android:src="@drawable/menu" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="19sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/search" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"
            android:background="@drawable/back_gradient" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Note: Do not include relative layout in this xml.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `TextView` by setting `0dip` to `android:layout_width` and set `android:layout_weight="1"`. So, the updated `TextView` XML be as follows...

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/back_gradient"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```